# SIngle point precsion for harmonic sequence

Tags: matlab, precision, numeric

I am trying to understand how can I by theory find the single precision of the summation of a harmonic sequence. I have rough idea for example,that the summation is ln(k) were k is the iteration step I think?? and the machine epsilion is 2^-23. But I get N> 2^-18, but The step I got after matlab is 2097153. Help anyone? Thanks a lot

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: I am not looking for code,Iam looking for theory to back up my code

Comment: I don't understand your comment, aren't you asking for a explanation why your code returns 2^-18 while you expect 2^-23? How should we explain that without knowing what code you run?

Comment: I am asking that what is the largest iteration that the sum of harmonic sequence stops increasing? If I had to make a guess. I can post my code if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this simple code:

```
s=single(0);
ix=1;
while(true)
    s_new=s+1/ix;
    if s_new==s
        break
    end
    s=s_new;
    ix=ix+1;
end
```

It stops with `ix=2097152`, the question is why?

The largest value you can add to `s_new` and not change the value is `eps(s_new)/2`, so we are looking for the point where `1/ix==eps(s_new)/2`. If you substitute `s_new` with the known approximation `log(ix+1)` you end up with `1/ix==eps(single(log(ix+1)))/2`, which is true for exactly the ix evaluated with the code:

```
>> f=@(x)(vpa(eps(single(log(x+1))))/2)-(1/vpa(x));
>> f(ix)

ans =

0.0

>> f(ix+1)

ans =

0.00000000000022737356702306650969194903757618

>> f(ix-1)

ans =

-0.00000000000022737378386350100684213964564307
```